# Best ip configuration for unique dual router setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

```
                                  current setup
             routerA--------------PTP dish link---------------routerB
      unique wan ip/internet                       unique wan ip/internet
```

subnet:     (A) 255.255.255.0              /                    (B) 255.255.255.0
router ip:   (A) 192.168.0.1               /                    (B) 192.168.0.10
dhcprange:   (A) 0.100-0.149               /                    (B) 0.150-0.199

I have two separate (mostly staitc) networks with two separate Internets linked via a PTP link. They both need to communicate as one(besides internet), and for the most part this setup has been working. There have been dhcp crossing issues and some other minor things though, which make me wonder if there is a better setup? The one below is my other idea but since it's a bit of work to shut things down was wondering if anyone thinks my network could be improved with some different numbers punched in? 
thx Jace

```
           routerA-----------------PTP dish link----------------routerB
      unique wan ip/internet                       unique wan ip/internet
```

subnet:      (A) 255.255.0.0               /                    (B) 255.255.0.0
router ip:   (A) 192.168.0.1               /                    (B) 192.168.1.1
dhcprange:   (A) 0.100-0.199               /                    (B) 1.100-1.199

Comment: Your DHCP issues could be prevented if you blocked DHCP traffic from crossing to the WAN-side of the PTP link.

Comment: Thanks I blocked the dhcp ports via the PTP link firewalls. In times past those firewalls have seemed a little undependable for me but we'll see =) Also still curious on peoples opinions on the best set of numbers or if I'm way off?.. thanks!